# Why am I getting [object Object] instead of JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the script:

```
$("#some_button").click(function() {

    var changed = [];

    $( 'input[id$="_1"]' ).each(function() {

        var new_id = this.id.replace( '_1', '_0' );

        if ( $(this).val() !== $( 'input#' + new_id ).val() ) {

            changed.push({id:new_id, new_val:$('input#' + new_id).val(), old_val:$(this).val()});

        }

    });

    alert(changed);

});
```

and it's gives me `[object Object],[object Object]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you don't have JSON. You have an array: `[]`. JSON is a string representation of a javascript object.

You could use the `JSON.stringify` method to generate a JSON string from an existing object:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(changed));
```

The `JSON.stringify` method is native in modern browsers but if you need to support legacy browsers you will need to include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) to your page. This script checks whether the browser supports natively `JSON.stringify` and uses it, or if it doesn't it provides a sample implementation.

Comment: @nami, no, you will have to include `json2.js` from here: http://www.json.org/js.html. The `JSON.stringify` method is native into modern browsers but legacy browsers don't support it.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is one way to display/encode JavaScript objects, but it's not used by default. When you convert an object to a string you'll normally just get a useless value like `"[object Object]"`.

If you want to convert your object into a JSON string, you need to use the `JSON.stringify` function. (This is included in new browsers, but requires a [JSON library](http://json.org/) in older ones.)

In your case, you probably want to replace your `alert` line with

```
alert(JSON.stringify(changed));
```

Comment: does jQuery have a built in json.stringifier?

Comment: @nami No, it doesn't. The jQuery developers recommend you use the library [json2.js](https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js) from json.org.

Comment: @nami Not as far as I know; for a library that works in newer and older browsers, try json2.js from [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).