# Post req.body.variable_name in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I want to post req.body.variable_name , see below my controller and services. Also nodejs side. I receive undefined back in responseAddROBO , where is the mistake ?

```
var ROBO = { host: $scope.hostname,
                subnet: $scope.subnet };

        $scope.addrobo = function () {
            apiSvc.post('/api/addrobo/', ROBO).success(function (response) {
                $scope.responseAddROBO = response;
            })
                .error(function (response) {
                    $scope.responseAddROBO = "NO RESPONSE";
                }
            );
            $scope.hostname = '';
            $scope.subnet = '';
        }
```

in services

```
.factory("apiSvc", function($http) {
        return {
            post: function(url,data) {
                return $http.post(url,data).success(function(response) {
                    return response
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

route on nodejs side:

```
router.post('/api/addrobo/', function (req, res, next) {      
    res.send(req.body.host,req.body.subnet);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Controller

Double check that you have injected `$scope` and `apiSvc`

Don't use `success`, use then

## Factory

In factory don't use `success` change your factory to

```
return $http.post(url,data);
```

Because you're getting success twice on the one piece of data currently when really it should be done once in the controller.

## You have an array

When your getting `[object Object]` you have an array not just a JSON object. You could use the `JSON.stringify` method to generate a JSON string from an existing object:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(changed));
```

src: [Why am I getting [object Object] instead of JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691015/why-am-i-getting-object-object-instead-of-json)

Give props to the author

Comment: now I am getting [object Object], double checked $scope and apiSvc injected in controller, removed success from factory and using then in controller

Comment: your getting a whole object back instead of what you want. you have to tell it what you want out of it.

Comment: check out this question. Some guy was getting the same response as you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691015/why-am-i-getting-object-object-instead-of-json

Comment: the problem is that inside my nodejs/express route  console.log(req.body.host + ' ' + req.body.subnet) shows undefined undefined..